# What would be the dimensions of on output matrix for the convolution of a $6\times 6\times 3$ input image and a $3\times3\times3$ kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, convolution, neural-networks

(Using a stride of zero and padding of zero.)

For an input image of size $6\times6$ with $3$ channels (therefore $6\times6\times3$) and a kernel of size $3\times3$ with $3$ channels, the equation for the convolution is given as follows:

$\sum_{m}^{k_1-1}\sum_{n}^{k_2-1}\sum_{C=1}^{3} K_{m,n,c}I_{i+m, j+n,c} + b$

I know that the size of a 2D convolution is given by:
$\frac{I-R}{s} + 1 = \frac{6-3}{1}+1 = 4$

So therefore, the first $2$ dimensions will be given as $4\times4$

But what are the dimensions of the 3rd dimension? Is my final dimension going to be $4\times4\times3$ or $4\times4\times1$?

Comment: 4*4*1, so that, if you had a bank of k kernels, the output would have been 4*4*k

Comment: Just to clarify what N74 said: The depth of the output after a convolution will always be equal to the number of kernels. Since you have 1 kernel, it will have a depth of 1.